# How to add certain number to laravel withCount method

Tags: php, laravel, count, eloquent

I have two related models, nothing special

```
class ModelOne extends Model {

    ...
    public function model_two() {
        return this->hasMany(ModelTwo::class, 'foreign_key');
    }
}
```

and:

```
class ModelTwo extends Model {

    ...
    public function model_one() {
        return this->belongsTo(ModelOne::class, 'foreign_key');
    }
}
```

And in my get function I have :

```
public function get() {
    return ModelOne::withCount('model_two')->get();
}
```

And I get nice response like this:

```
{
   "property_one": "property_one_value",
   "property_two": "property_two_value",
   "property_three": "property_three_value"
   "model_two_count: 5
}
```

But what I need is to add certain number to that count, for example '2', so instead of json object above, I would like to have it like this:

```
  {
   "property_one": "property_one_value",
   "property_two": "property_two_value",
   "property_three": "property_three_value"
   "model_two_count: 7
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `withCount()` do this, you could override `withCount()` and `getRelationCountQuery` methods in the model.

An easier way is to modify collection by using the [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) helper:

```
public function get() {
    $data = ModelOne::withCount('model_two')->get();
    return $data->map(function ($i) {
        $i->model_two_count = $i->model_two_count + 2;
        return $i;
    });
}
```